To get users SimID and device id in my flutter app
I want to get user Sim Id and Device Id for my flutter app. How can i get access from Android?
I have tried Platform channel to get Imei and Sim Id But it doesn't help.Do i have to contact support team or Any other method for fix this ussue

TL;DR: You can't.
All non-resettable device identifiers are no longer available starting from Android 10 unless you have special carrier permissions/you are developing an OEM app.
For reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#data-ids

How bank apps get access of these permissions.
